# Efficient days between two dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```py
# works
pre_start['exposure_days'] = (datetime.now() - pd.to_datetime(pre_start['First_Exposure']))

# doesn't work
pre_start['exposure_days'] = (datetime.now() - pd.to_datetime(pre_start['First_Receive_Date'])).days
```

The error I get is `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'`.

Without doing something obnoxious and inefficient like
`pre_start['real_exposure_days'] = pre_start['exposure_days'].apply(lambda x: x.days)` is there a way to get the number of days, circumventing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is use the [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor:

```
pre_start['exposure_days'] = (datetime.now() - pd.to_datetime(pre_start['First_Receive_Date'])).dt.days
```